# Multi-thread performance in Java when working with a list

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to the multi-threading concept and I'm creating a simple Java program to experience with multiple threads and stuff.
In my program, I simply have a linked list, and I create a thread to just remove list items from the beginning. I implement the **Runnable** interface and this is what the **run** method of my thread looks like: (I set **list** in the constructor)

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Starting...");

    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        synchronized (list) {
            list.removeFirst();             
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Finished!");
}
```

In the **main** method, I add a huge number of items to the linked list (10,000,000) and simply create instances of this class to run concurrently and I measure the time:

```
    Thread my1 = new Thread(new MyThread("my1", list));
    Thread my2 = new Thread(new MyThread("my2", list));
    Thread my3 = new Thread(new MyThread("my3", list));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    my1.start();
    my2.start();
    my3.start();
    my1.join();
    my2.join();
    my3.join();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Main finished in " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
```

Interestingly enough, when I run my program using these 3 threads, I receive the message:

```
Main finished in 444 milliseconds
```

But, when I use only a single thread, I receive the message:

```
Main finished in 223 milliseconds
```

Is there anyway I can tweak the code to run actually faster when using multiple threads???

Thank you in advance

Comment: just loose all the reference by `list = null;` why do you want to remove elements one by one if your purpose is to remove all faster

Comment: as soon as you're using synchronized - you're gaining nothing from different threads, only making it worse because of synchronization, basically you usually gain nothing in case of shared resources as in this example

Comment: also, the `list.empty()` test outside of the synch block is not thread-safe.

Comment: In my main problem, the list holds objects that determine an action to be made (add or find elements in a tree)... I have to read these objects and perform the required actions until the list is empty... I cannot figure out how I can use multiple threads to improve performance...

Comment: Are those operations demonstrably expensive? Are they independent, or do they depend on previous outputs.

Comment: the operations are limited to two actions: find an element in a tree, or add an element to the tree. I'm supposed to read the list containing objects specifying these tasks and perform their required action until the "task list" is empty... I don't know how I can improve speed using multiple threads

Comment: So it sounds like these operations are all contending for a common object. Nothing you can do to improve performance by parallelizing; the only realistic target is trying to make the operations cheaper.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I make them cheaper?

Answer (score 2):

This example cannot benefit from multiple threads, on the contrary: You are adding overhead by synchronizing access to the list, so that only one thread can access it at a time. While this is necessary for correctness, the actual operation is so low-overhead that the synchronization dominates.

This scenario could make sense if your worker threads did some expensive computation or I/O with the data from the list. If that is the actual goal, you should include this in your benchmark.

Comment: Actually, this was a practice for a bigger problem for my programming assignment in which list items are objects that we should read and do something based on their properties (more precisely, find or add elements in a tree)... There has to be a way to improve performance, but nothing comes to my mind

Comment: The "doing something" part might be what actually benefits from multiple threads. Would they all work on the same tree?

Comment: I'll try to be concise: I have a search tree initially containing items. I'm supposed to create a list of "Tasks" that can do two things: search for an item or add an item. I need to use multiple threads to read these "Tasks" from the list and do their jobs until the list is empty, and finally output the resulting tree to show that the "add"s have been applied

Answer (score 0):

You've run into what's called the *critical path*, the portion of the code that has to be be properly ordered and thus can't be parallelized. In this example, the critical path is most of your program, so you won't gain anything by trying to use multiple threads. Multiple threads provide a benefit only when they do a substantial amount of work (I/O, localized computation) that's independent.

Comment: I briefly described the thing I need to do in the comment above... I was thinking about the problem and I started with manipulating this simple list to get the idea, but I still don't know how I can improve the speed